# Mac OSX Dismiss multiple view controller presented by Show Segue

Tags: swift, macos, segue, nsviewcontroller

I have a view controller where I present another view controller with a "show" type segue. I want to allow multiple copies of the view to be presented and then when the presenting view controller is closed, dismiss any of the views presented by the show segue that are still open. If I use a popup segue, then any previous existing view is dismissed and that is not the desired action that I am looking for. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that I came up with. Basically capture an array of view controllers in the prepareforsegue method, then in the viewwilldisappear method iterate through the array and close the windows associated with the view controllers.

prepareforsegue

```
    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("in prepare for seque")

    if (segue.identifier!.rawValue == "viewSegmentsSegue"){
        let viewController = segue.destinationController as! NSViewController
        self.segmentsArray?.append(viewController)
        }

}
```

viewwilldisappear()

```
    override func viewWillDisappear() {
    for segments:NSViewController in segmentsArray!{
        segments.view.window?.close()

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works for macos. Amazing!

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand your question but maybe you could use a sub view controller inside the actual view controller.

Comment: I want to know how to dismiss multiple views that were created by a show segue from the presenting view in either an IBAction or viewwilldisappear method for Mac OSX. View A creates multiple copies view B. How do I dismiss any existing view Bs from view A?

Comment: Hi, sorry I couldn't help as I am not familiar with coding for Mac OS X. Unfortunately I don't know how else you could do it... Maybe try using apple's documentation?